# Reading a text file from kubernetes root using java springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, drone.io

I am writing a secret to a file using Drone while deploying to Kubernates.
How can read this file using java Springboot?

**Drone commands**

```
 commands:
   - touch naspvtkey.txt
   - ls -a
   - echo "$NASPVTKEY" > naspvtkey.txt
```

**Drone outputs:**

```
+ touch naspvtkey.txt -------> created the file
+ ls -a
.DS_Store
.drone.yml
.drone.yml.sig
.git
.gitignore
.mvn
Dockerfile
README.md
kubernetes
mvnw
naspvtkey.txt
pom.xml
src
+ echo "$NASPVTKEY" > naspvtkey.txt ---------> added my secret
```

I am trying to access the file using

```
  file = new File("/naspvtkey.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure container user has permission to create file in root directory.